# Trailing slash and initial www

Tags: .htaccess, slash

I have this htaccess:

```
  RewriteEngine On

  # redirect with www
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mydomain [NC]
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1/ [R=301,L]

  # add .php internally
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [L,QSA]
```

So my .php files can be called without the .php extension.

But I'd like them to be called only with a trailing slash. So when this trailing slash is not given, it should be appended with a 301. The problem I have is that this is giving me problems with the initial www, and the .php extension itself (sometimes it is adding recursively .php).

How can it be done?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need to add something like this before your last rewrite rule, to avoid rewriting URIs that already end in .php

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.php$
```