# .htaccess - Remove trailing slash

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, trailing-slash

Currently I have a htaccess in my wordpress site that adds a trailing slash to my urls. Somehow I can't figure out where it is in my htaccess.

Can you tell which one does that in the following code? And how to remove trailing slash in the current code?

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
#RewriteRule ^tester$ "http\:\/\/www\.domain-name\.org\/test" [R=301,L]
#RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain-name\.org$ [OR]
#RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.domain-name\.org$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^equip\.domain-name\.org$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.equip\.domain-name\.org$
RewriteRule ^/?$ "http\:\/\/www\.domain-name\.org\/equip\/" [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(.*\.php)$ $2 [L]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Trailing slash and initial www](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2261455/trailing-slash-and-initial-www)

Comment: hi tomasz, thanks for the reply. I tried the accepted answer but still it doesn't work on my site. there is still a trailing slash.

Answer (score 0):

With that:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?equip\.domain-name\.org$
RewriteRule ^/?$ http://www.domain-name.org/equip/" [R=302,L]
```

(302 just for test)
An example with the trailing slash (before and after rewrite) ?